dxDataGrid: unable to use keyboard navigation for column reordered
Is there a way to enable keyboard navigation to reorder columns  (similar to drag and drop using mouse)?
By enabling the allowColumnReordering property, columns can be reordered using a mouse, but we want to be able to do same using the keyboard only.
import "devextreme/ui/data_grid";
...
allowColumnReordering: true,

